While installing storybook.js I am getting error "Int.default is not a function" in a current project
I have a Vue 3 application running on VITE.
I am trying to add Storybook to the project.
As stated in storybook doc.. I run npx storybook@latest init
while installing the dependencies the setup throws error "Error: TypeError: Int.default is not a function"
Error Screenshot here
I searched online but couldnt find any solution to this

See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551 , full error should be presented as text . The question needs https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve , it's very specific to your case. You will need a "hello world" project that is based on your current project can reproduce the problem from scratch. That Storybook code is minified doesn't help the situation. It can be only seen that the problem happens when Storybook processes the project's dependencies. Probably there's something wrong with them.
